# Pylint syntax error not suppressing despite the `disable` comment

Tags: .net, python-2.7, ironpython, pylint, pyansys

I'm writing scripts for Ansys Mechanical, which are written in IronPython 2.7.0.40. In my script, I need to assign a property to `ContactTimeStepControls.None`. Note that the `None` here is NOT the `None` object.[1]

My issue is that the Pylint extension in VS Code is flagging the use of `None` here as a syntax error (probably because it thinks it IS the `None` object) and refusing to evaluate the rest of the code. Here are there error messages it gives:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax (file:///[PathToMyScript], line 264) compile [Ln 264, Col 80]

> Parsing failed: 'invalid syntax (, line 264)' Pylint(E0001:syntax-error) [Ln 264, Col 81]

I've tried disabling that error message the following two ways:

```
# pylint: disable=syntax-error
Cxn.TimeStepControls = ContactTimeStepControls.None
```

and

```
# pylint: disable=E0001
Cxn.TimeStepControls = ContactTimeStepControls.None
```

Both fail to suppress the error.

Here's a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image: Example of Pylint Error]

I therefore have three questions:

1. Am I doing something wrong with the Pylint suppression?
2. Is there some means of structuring the code to avoid the error (note that I can't change the members of `ContactTimeStepControls`)?
3. Is there some other means of suppressing the Pylint errors on this line?

[1] Output from `dir(ContactTimeStepControls)` is this (see **bolded** item):

`['AutomaticBisection', 'CompareTo', 'Equals', 'Format', 'GetHashCode', 'GetName', 'GetNames', 'GetType', 'GetTypeCode', 'GetUnderlyingType', 'GetValues', 'HasFlag', 'IsDefined', 'MemberwiseClone',` **'None'**`, 'Parse', 'PredictForImpact', 'ReferenceEquals', 'ToBoolean', 'ToByte', 'ToChar', 'ToDateTime', 'ToDecimal', 'ToDouble', 'ToInt16', 'ToInt32', 'ToInt64', 'ToObject', 'ToSByte', 'ToSingle', 'ToString', 'ToType', 'ToUInt16', 'ToUInt32', 'ToUInt64', 'TryParse', 'UseImpactConstraints', '__and__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__or__', '__rand__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__ror__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__xor__', 'value__']`

## Edit:

I just discovered another place where this is likely to occur that will probably be experienced more commonly by people. The `DialogResult` property ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)) of the `System.Windows.Forms` module from Microsoft's .NET API has a `None` property, which would produce the same effect.

Comment: I'd be surprised if `.None` was really causing the syntax error.  In my experience, mysterious syntax errors are usually caused by some error (often a missing parentheses or bracket) on a previous line.  Can you post that section of the code, along with the five or so previous lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, you can parse the enum from a string

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import DialogResult

result = DialogResult.Parse(DialogResult, "None")
```

or in Mechanical scripting (tested in 2024 R1)

```py
Cxn.TimeStepControls = ContactTimeStepControls.Parse(ContactTimeStepControls, "None")
```

Once again not ideal, but at least it avoids the Pylint errors.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors cannot be disabled, they indicate that pylint is not compatible with Iron python and cannot parse your file. I'm on mobile so I can't link the Iron python issue from the github repo but there's one.

Comment: That's surprising and disappointing. If you can provide the link to the issue on Github, I'd very much appreciate it. Is there any workaround possible at all? I guess I could comment out that line, fix the issues in the rest of the file then uncomment. I'm open to other options though as well, if you're aware of any.

Comment: A little dated: https://github.com/pylint-dev/astroid/issues/329 but still relevant imo. Can't find anytbing specific to ironpython at this point, could you create an issue maybe ?

Comment: I found a workaround. See my answer. It's not ideal since it relies on `eval()`, but I think the risk is low and the benefit significant.

Comment: That's a clever trick!

Comment: The solution provided by @Tzane is even better yet!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround using `eval()`:

Before:

[image: Code with Syntax Error]

After:

[image: Code without Syntax Error]

Obviously, the use of `eval()` makes this less than ideal. But the risk is low since the text is not being generated dynamically, and the benefit of being able to have Pylint evaluate the entire code greatly outweighs the downside of needing to use `eval()`.

Comment: While the above works, the solution provided by @Tzane is better.